# Overriding default alert and confirm boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on submitting a form using the traditional submit button and not ajax.(Some framework dependency is not allowing it)

I want to use the confirm box before the user submits the form.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<!-- <link type="text/css" src="http://localhost/maverick/craftpip/dist/jquery-confirm.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/maverick/craftpip/dist/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script> -->

<!-- CSS dependencies -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootbox code -->
<script src="http://localhost/maverick/bootbox-master/bootbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('submit', $('#form1'), function(){


             alert("works!!!");

             bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
             console.log("Alert Callback");
             return false;
});

            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="test" action="" type="" id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="message" />
        <input type="submit" name="Enter" value="Enter" id="mySubmit" />
    </form>

</body>
```

The default confirm and alert box works but the bootbox which is a wrapper around it fails and the form is submitted without confirming.
How can I override the default behavior with the wrapper one?

Comment: You have to use *preventDefault()* method of the event object, that should be a parameter for the *submit* event handler function.

Comment: I see you have used `$('#form1')` in your code. Instead use `'#form1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit after confirm/alert add some variable as state of confirming.

```
 var confirmed=false;//our state of alert/confirm
 $(document).on('submit', '#form1', function(e){


         if (!confirmed)
         e.preventDefault();//if not confirmed submit is blocked

         bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {

            //ok we confirmed/alert was shown
            confirmed=true;//set state on true

            //run again
            $('#form1').submit(); //trigger form again

         });

});
```

So on first submit fire we get submit stop by **e.preventDefault** and alert will be shown, after alert - **confirmed** is set to true and next submit is triggered - then form will be submited because **confirmed** is true and **e.preventDefault** is not called.

Comment: I am just working on the solution as the actual form is each row in the table.I will accept it once I am done! (Y) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("[type=submit]").on("click",function(){

        alert("works!!!");

        return false;

    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    
    <form id="form1" action="http://www.google.com">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("[type=submit]").on("click",function(){
        alert("works!!!");
        return false;
            
        })
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```